# "Runtime Error '5' in VBA when Setting Range from RefEdit Control for Spreadsheet Compare"

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a VBA macro in Excel that's designed for spreadsheet comparison. I'm using a `RefEdit` control to allow users to select a range, but I'm encountering a "Runtime Error '5': Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" when trying to set this range in VBA.

Here's the relevant code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XktYV.png)

The error occurs at the line Set refRange = Range(refDatabaseStyleColumn.Value).

I've ensured that the refDatabaseStyleColumn control contains a valid Excel range address, and other controls like txtDatabaseStyleColumn and optDatabaseStyleCompare are correctly named and present on my form.

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: With great probability the refDatabaseStyleColumn is not accessible from your code because of the scope or visibility of the modules. But in the future pls.  don't insert code as picture place it as text on the sheet with appropriate formatting.

Comment: don't know if it's relevant, but you're writing "Range(refDatabaseStyleColumn.Value)", while the "Value" bit is missing in your code.